# C++ double cant be equal to two int division

Tags: c++, double, division

I am a bit stuck with this problem:

```
int a = 5, b = 2;
double c = a / b;
cout << c;
```

This outputs:

```
2
```

Why ?

I can by pass this by using:

```
double aa = a,
bb = b;
c = aa / bb;
```

This outputs:

```
2.5
```

Help ! :(

Comment: Hint: C++ has different kinds of division. The kind of division done in any given context depends on the types of the two operands, a and b in this case.

Comment: It outputs 2 because b is an integer. The math is done as an integer then converted to a double.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ language, any arithmetic operation between two integer values will return an int value. Said differently, the integer division **is** the Euclidian division. And only then that integer value is casted to a double.

If you want a double operation, you must force the division to operate on double values,  either by casting one operand to double, or by multiplying it by `1.0` which is a double constant :

```
double c = 1.0 * a / b;
```

or

```
double c = static_cast<double>(a) / b;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to at least cast one of the ints to a double:

```
double c = a/(double)b;
```

Comment: better to use C++ style cast

Comment: There's already an answer by Serge Ballesta on the C++ cast style.Though this looks much easier for beginners that is a better practice.